# Failed to create pod sandbox kubernetes error

Tags: kubernetes, weave

I have a `Ubuntu 16.04` which is acting as kubernetes master. I have installed kuber v1.13.1 and using weave for networking. I have 2 `Raspberry pi` devices running the same version of kubernetes. I created a cluster and joined the raspberry pi to `Ubuntu` kube master. I have started a deployment and everything looks to be working fine.

When I checked the logs of the container, I found out that it was not able to connect to the internet. I tried pinging but got no results. When I run the command to describe the pod, I got following:

`Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  42m (x3 over 42m)   kubelet, node02  (combined from similar events): Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "dea99f80488031b84b7b1f934343e54d877adf931071401651628505d52f55f9" network for pod "deployment-cnfc5": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "deployment-cnfc5_matrix-device" network: unable to allocate IP address: Post http://127.0.0.1:6784/ip/dea99f80488031b84b7b1f934343e54d877adf931071401651628505d52f55f9: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6784: connect: connection refused`

I have checked the directory `/etc/cni/net.d` and it contains `10-weave.conflist` on both master and worker node. I have also checked the directory `/opt/cni/bin` and found below on `master` node:

`bridge flannel     ipvlan    macvlan  ptp     tuning  weave-ipam  weave-plugin-2.5.1
dhcp    host-local  loopback  portmap  sample  vlan    weave-net`

and on worker, I got below:

`bridge flannel     ipvlan    macvlan  ptp     tuning  weave-ipam  weave-plugin-2.5.0
dhcp    host-local  loopback  portmap  sample  vlan    weave-net   weave-plugin-2.5.1`

Please can anyone please let me know what can I do to resolve this issue.? Thanks.

I initiated the kube master by using below commands:

```
sudo kubeadm init --token-ttl=0 --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.0.142
```

and installed weave using:

```
kubectl apply -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')"
```

Comment: provide parameters you used during kubeadm init? And how you configured weave?

Comment: @VKR Apologies for late reply, I have edited my question with the details you mentioned